# WebAPI Gzip when returning HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, gzip

I have a WebAPI controller that returns an `HttpResponseMessage` and I want to add gzip compression. This is the server code:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.IO.Compression;

[Route("SomeRoute")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] string value)
{
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

    context.Response.Filter = new GZipStream(context.Response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);

    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders["Accept-encoding"] = true;

    return new SomeClass().SomeRequest(value);
}
```

And this is the client code for the ajax call, using jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/SomeRoute",
    type: "POST",
    cache: "false",
    data: SomeData,
    beforeSend: function (jqXHR) { jqXHR.setRequestHeader('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip'); },
    success: function(msg) { ... }
```

When I run this, the server code returns without bugging but the client bugs:

```
(failed)
net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED
```

[image]

When I look with Fiddler, this is what I see:

[image]

What do I need to change to make the web service return gzipped content that the client processes normally? I know I could also do this with an HttpModule or through some setting on IIS but neither option fits the scenario of the hosting:

[image]

**Please note that I'm not looking for an IIS setting because I don't have access to that (hosting).**

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10446108/263003

Comment: take a look at http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Apr/28/GZipDeflate-Compression-in-ASPNET-MVC

Comment: @JeowLiHuan: I was hoping I could do it in much fewer steps.

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3653766/2164198 and try to use suggested wrapper to avoid undesired behavior. Also see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7629079/2164198

Comment: By the looks of it you can do it directly on IIS. The link is a bit old --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702124/enable-iis7-gzip

Comment: Note: I'm NOT looking for an IIS setting because I don't have access to that (hosting).

Comment: Your question didn't mention about the iis constraint so i added it.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kiranchalla/archive/2012/09/04/handling-compression-accept-encoding-sample.aspx

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**If you have access to IIS configuration**

You cant just apply the header and hope it will be gzipped - the response will not be zipped.

You need remove the header you added and ensure you have the dynamic compression and static content compression are enabled on your IIS server.

One of the commenter's mentioned a good resource link here at stakoverflow that show how to do that:

[Enable IIS7 gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702124/enable-iis7-gzip)

Note it will only work setting the value in web.config if dynamic compression is already installed (which is not in a default install of IIS)

You can find the information about this on MSDN documentation: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpcompression

**Simple compression**

Below is using a simple example of doing your own compression this example is using the Web Api MVC 4 project from visual studio project templates. To get compression working for HttpResponseMessages you have to implement a custom MessageHandler. See below a working example.

See the code implementation below.

*Please note that I tried to keep the method doing the same as your example.*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        public class Person
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
        }
        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders["accept-encoding"] = true;

            return new [] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders["accept-encoding"] = true;

            var TheHTTPResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK); 
            TheHTTPResponse.Content = new StringContent("{\"asdasdasdsadsad\": 123123123 }", Encoding.UTF8, "text/json"); 

            return TheHTTPResponse;
        }

        public class EncodingDelegateHandler : DelegatingHandler
        {
            protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>((responseToCompleteTask) =>
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = responseToCompleteTask.Result;

                    if (response.RequestMessage.Headers.AcceptEncoding != null &&
                        response.RequestMessage.Headers.AcceptEncoding.Count > 0)
                    {
                        string encodingType = response.RequestMessage.Headers.AcceptEncoding.First().Value;

                        response.Content = new CompressedContent(response.Content, encodingType);
                    }

                    return response;
                },
                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
            }
        }

        public class CompressedContent : HttpContent
        {
            private HttpContent originalContent;
            private string encodingType;

            public CompressedContent(HttpContent content, string encodingType)
            {
                if (content == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("content");
                }

                if (encodingType == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("encodingType");
                }

                originalContent = content;
                this.encodingType = encodingType.ToLowerInvariant();

                if (this.encodingType != "gzip" && this.encodingType != "deflate")
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Encoding '{0}' is not supported. Only supports gzip or deflate encoding.", this.encodingType));
                }

                // copy the headers from the original content
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>> header in originalContent.Headers)
                {
                    this.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value);
                }

                this.Headers.ContentEncoding.Add(encodingType);
            }

            protected override bool TryComputeLength(out long length)
            {
                length = -1;

                return false;
            }

            protected override Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
            {
                Stream compressedStream = null;

                if (encodingType == "gzip")
                {
                    compressedStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress, leaveOpen: true);
                }
                else if (encodingType == "deflate")
                {
                    compressedStream = new DeflateStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress, leaveOpen: true);
                }

                return originalContent.CopyToAsync(compressedStream).ContinueWith(tsk =>
                {
                    if (compressedStream != null)
                    {
                        compressedStream.Dispose();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also add the new message handler to the config of your app.

```
using System.Web.Http;
using MvcApplication1.Controllers;

namespace MvcApplication1
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.MessageHandlers.Add(new ValuesController.EncodingDelegateHandler());

            config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
        }
    }
}
```

The Custom handler was put together by - Kiran Challa (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kiranchalla/archive/2012/09/04/handling-compression-accept-encoding-sample.aspx)

There are better examples that implement deflating of inbound streams too you can see examples of that below:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/557232/Implementing-a-Custom-DelegatingHandler-in-ASP-NET
- http://ronaldrosiernet.azurewebsites.net/blog/2013/07/16/implement_compression_in_aspnet_web_api

Additionally I found a really nice project that supports all of this on github.

- https://github.com/azzlack/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.MessageHandlers.Compression

Note while I arrived to this answer by myself Simon in your comments suggested this approach 2 days ago from the date of this answer.

Comment: I'm not looking for an IIS solution because I don't have access to that. That's why I need to do the compression out of WebAPI.

Comment: Use the example on http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-web-api-compression that does it outside of iis.

Comment: That doesn't work in a hosted enviro: <httpCompression directory="%TEMP%\iisexpress\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
    <scheme name="gzip" dll="%IIS_BIN%\gzip.dll" />

Comment: if dynamic compression is not installed you wont be able to use it

Comment: you have to implement your own using the classes on ben fosters post

Comment: the sample on msdn you dont need to use the attribute on httpCompression or the scheme element.

Comment: Everybody says "it's easy, take a look at this link". Your answer lots of links, but no code.

Comment: I can provide you an working example... all you had to do was ask. :(

Comment: Ok, code is always better. I have the web service setup as shown in the question and I guess I'm just looking for the 3-5 lines of code that do the compression of the HTTP Response.

Comment: I will post something tonight

Comment: I see that your screenshot shows it works but the code is not returning an HttpResponseMessage. The code won't work when you return a raw HttpResponseMessage, that's the problem I'm looking to solve.

Comment: Remove all the GET requests and just leave the POST. Then, replace your code with this: HttpResponseMessage TheHTTPResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
TheHTTPResponse.Content = new StringContent("{\"d\": " + "test" + "}", Encoding.UTF8, "text/json");
return TheHTTPResponse; Run it and it'll return a json string. Now the problem is to make it return a gziped HttpResponseMessage. And that's when it doesn't work.

Comment: Yep i will check it today. Might to use the common fabrik stuff on this

Comment: I have added a working example now, finally it is working with http response messages.. had to implement a custom message handler.

Comment: I found some even better examples you can use check my answer now

Comment: What comment are you talking about?

Comment: I haven't stolen Any bodies comment

Comment: I broke my back getting to this answer and i havent used anyone elses answers here all places i have taken stuff from have been properly attributed.

Comment: Probably what happen here is that there is another question in so that has an answer similar. I didnt see any had i found one i would have attributed. No need to down vote.

Comment: Oh now i can see your comment on the question i could attribute to your comment but i arrived at that port with out the help of your comment since i had missed it. Why didnt you post an answer...

Comment: @SimonMourier I didnt see your comment.. infact I found a ton of example online that i even noted on my answer i could have put another example which I almost did, it just happen I used the Kiran challas one because it has decompression and compression. ok I didnt steal your comment I found it on my own accord.

Comment: @SimonMourier but to be a fair I added an attribution to you at the bottom

Comment: Thanks for this, suspect you mean accept-encoding rather than accept-enconding!

Comment: @TheSenator yes indeed well spotted

Answer (score 53):

Add these NuGet packages:

> Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Extensions.Compression.Server
> System.Net.Http.Extensions.Compression.Client

Then and add one line of code to `App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Insert(0, new ServerCompressionHandler(new GZipCompressor(), new DeflateCompressor()));
```

That will do the trick!

Details at:

- [NuGet package page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.MessageHandlers.Compression/)
- [GitHub](https://github.com/azzlack/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.MessageHandlers.Compression)

**Updated after comment from @JCisar

**Update for ASP.Net Core**

Nuget Package is

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression

Comment: This is so much better than turning on dynamic IIS compression

Comment: Thanks!  Although, the package does say it is obsolete (I am guessing as of 01-28-2016).  Anyone know if this is replaced by something that I should be using instead?  I don't see any mention of it.

Comment: @JCisar according to the package author, you're supposed to be using [those new packages](https://github.com/azzlack/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.MessageHandlers.Compression) that are being maintained by him.

Comment: Note I could not get this to work via this method and in fact had to use `config.MessageHandlers.Insert(0, new ServerCompressionHandler(new GZipCompressor(), new DeflateCompressor()));` within the `Register` method

Comment: This is an obsolete package, it only installs the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Extensions.Compression.Server and System.Net.Http.Extensions.Compression.Client packages.

Comment: @JCisar Updated .. thanks for pointing out. Updated the links.

Comment: how to make it work, only if user requested to do so?

Comment: I think it's worth noting that both of those packages are not official Microsoft packages, despite their misleading name.

Comment: If you're working with a "legacy" ASP.NET site, circa .NET Framework 4.5/4.6/4.7/etc. you'll want these packages **BUT** be sure to seek them out on nuget with ".StrongName" or they won't load. I don't know why they split these into different versions and didn't just publish only the strong name versions, but they didn't so:

Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Extensions.Compression.Server.StrongName
System.Net.Http.Extensions.Compression.Client.StrongName (actually, this DNE, but you can fork the repo and create it)

Answer (score 5):

One Solution **without** editing any IIS Setting or Installing any **Nuget** package is to add a **MessageHandler** to your WEB API.

This will catch requests with the "AcceptEncoding" Header and compress them using the Build in **System.IO.Compression** libraries.

```
public class CompressHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private static CompressHandler _handler;
    private CompressHandler(){}
    public static CompressHandler GetSingleton()
    {
        if (_handler == null)
            _handler = new CompressHandler();
        return _handler;
    }
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>((responseToCompleteTask) =>
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = responseToCompleteTask.Result;
            var acceptedEncoding =GetAcceptedEncoding(response);
            if(acceptedEncoding!=null)
                response.Content = new CompressedContent(response.Content, acceptedEncoding);

            return response;
        },
        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
    }
    private string GetAcceptedEncoding(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        string encodingType=null;
        if (response.RequestMessage.Headers.AcceptEncoding != null && response.RequestMessage.Headers.AcceptEncoding.Any())
        {
            encodingType = response.RequestMessage.Headers.AcceptEncoding.First().Value;
        }
        return encodingType;
    }


}

    public class CompressedContent : HttpContent
{
    private HttpContent originalContent;
    private string encodingType;

    public CompressedContent(HttpContent content, string encodingType)
    {
        if (content == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("content");
        }

        if (encodingType == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("encodingType");
        }

        originalContent = content;
        this.encodingType = encodingType.ToLowerInvariant();

        if (this.encodingType != "gzip" && this.encodingType != "deflate")
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Encoding '{0}' is not supported. Only supports gzip or deflate encoding.", this.encodingType));
        }

        // copy the headers from the original content
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>> header in originalContent.Headers)
        {
            this.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value);
        }

        this.Headers.ContentEncoding.Add(encodingType);
    }

    protected override bool TryComputeLength(out long length)
    {
        length = -1;

        return false;
    }

    protected override Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
    {
        Stream compressedStream = null;

        if (encodingType == "gzip")
        {
            compressedStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress, leaveOpen: true);
        }
        else if (encodingType == "deflate")
        {
            compressedStream = new DeflateStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress, leaveOpen: true);
        }

        return originalContent.CopyToAsync(compressedStream).ContinueWith(tsk =>
        {
            if (compressedStream != null)
            {
                compressedStream.Dispose();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And add this handler to your Global.asax.cs

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Insert(0, CompressHandler.GetSingleton());
```

Kudos to Ben Foster.
[ASP.NET Web API Compression](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-web-api-compression)

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed to replace some outdated NuGet packages. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just an addendum to enabling compression in IIS via the `applicationHost.config` file.

[Use the IIS config manager](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EnablingDynamicCompressionGzipDeflateForWCFDataFeedsODataAndOtherCustomServicesInIIS7.aspx) to make the changes or `notepad.exe` to edit the file. I was using `Notepad++` and even though the file was saving, it actually was not.

Something to do with 32/64bit environments, configs and the programs that edit them. Ruined my afternoon!!